# How to prove $x$ doesn't lie in $R_M$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain. $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Let $x=a/b \in K-R$ and $a \notin (b)$. How do I prove $x \notin R_M$ where $M$ is a maximal ideal containing $b$? The statement is "intuitively" clear to me but struggling to find the rigorous proof.

Comment: $b \in R$ , so a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ such that $b \in M$.

Comment: @Mohan: you should take a careful look at the definition of localization of a ring at a prime ideal. All elements of $R_M$ are of the form $c/d$ where $d \not \in M.$

Comment: Yes I know that. So, if $x=ab^{-1}$ why can't $cd^{-1}=ab^{-1}$ in $K$?

Comment: Do you mean that there exists some $M$ satisfying $x \notin R_M$, or is $M$ given?

Comment: M is not given. M is some maximal ideal containing b.

Comment: As your comments show you are struggling to find a rigorous question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer. I assume the following is meant: We have an integral domain $R$ with elements $a,b \in R$ satisfying $a \notin (b)$. Then we want to find some maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ satisfying $b \in M$ and $\frac{a}{b} \in Q(R) \setminus R_M$.

I can prove something weaker: Assuming $a \notin \sqrt{(b)}$ (i.e. $a^n \notin (b)$ for all $n$), there is some prime ideal satisfying this. If $R$ is Jacobson (for example of finite type over a field), we also find a maximal ideal satisfying this.

Proof: Observe that $a/b \in R_M \Rightarrow a \in M$ (since $a/b=c/d$ with $d \notin M$ gives $ad=bc \in M$ etc.). Therefore it suffices to find some prime ideal containing $b$ not not $a$. If it not existed, we would have $V(b) \subseteq V(a)$, thus $a \in \sqrt{(a)}=I(V(a)) \subseteq I(V(b))=\sqrt{(b)}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Can't it be proved easily if we assume $M$ to just a maximal ideal? Let $x \in K-R$. There exists a maximal ideal $M$ such that $x \notin R_M$?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Let $x \in K−R$. Does there exists a maximal ideal $M$ of $R$ such that $x \notin R_M$?

Answer (score 0):

This seems so clear from the very definition that I'm beginning to suspect I might misunderstand something. By definition

$$R_M:=\left\{\,\frac{r}{s}\;;\;s\notin M\right\}$$

Thus, for *any* $\,b\in M\,$ and **any** $\,a\in R\,$ , clearly $\,\displaystyle{\frac{a}{b}\notin R_M}\,$ ...**unless** $\,a\in (b)\,$ , since then it can be

$$a=tb\Longrightarrow \frac{a}{b}=\frac{tb}{b}=\frac{t}{1}\in R_M$$

Comment: My question is this. Let us embed $R_M$ in $Frac(R)=K$. Now, let $x \in R_M$, by defintion of localization x=$cd^{-1}$ where $ d \notin M$. By why can't there be an  $a \in R$ and $b \in M$ such that $ab^{1}=cd^{-1}$ in $K$?

Comment: @DonAntonio: This proof is not complete. You show the wrong direction. The other one does not work the same, since $r/s=a/b$ does not mean $r=a,s=b$, but rather $rb=sa$. Besides, YACP has already shown that it's false when $M$ is not specified.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion arises from the notation? $R_M$ is seen here as a subring of $K$.

Comment: Yes,$R_M$ is seen as a subring of K here.

Comment: I've no time right now, but isn't $\,R_M\,$ the localization of $\,M\,$? That's what I wrote and that's what I meant to in my answer...

Comment: Yes, $R_M$ is the localization of $M$ seen as a subring of $K$.